# Return values of function which just set a value

Tags: solidity

If I have a function that just sets a value like this:

```
  function setBytes(
    bytes32 _value
  ) public {
    testBytes = _value;
  }
```

Should this kind of functions return a value or should the function remain without a return if the function is called from another contract? In some code examples, I have seen that this kind of functions returns true. Like this:

```
  function setBytes(
    bytes32 _value
  ) public returns(bool success) {
    testBytes = _value;
    return true;
  }
```

What is the best practice in such cases and what is the purpose of returning true?

Answer (score 2):

There are of course many opinions about this.

In my opinion a function should return a `boolean` if it's unsure whether the operation will succeed or not and when it's important to know whether it succeeded. I don't see any benefit in returning anything if the function will surely succeed (such as setting a value). In theory even just setting a value may fail due to running out of gas but returning a `boolean` wouldn't help anything there anyway.